# Inbuilt Regex class or Parser.How to extract text between the tags from html file?

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have html file in which there is table content and other information in my c#.net application.

I want to parse the table contents for only some columns.Then should I use parser of html or ***Replace*** method of ***Regex*** in .net ?

And if I use the parser then how to use parser? Will parser extract the inforamation which is between the tags? If yes then how to use ? If possible show the example because I am new to parser.

If I use ***Replace*** method of ***Regex*** class then in that method how to pass the file name for which I want to extract the information ?

***Edit*** : I want to extract information from the table in html file. For that how can I use html agility parser ? What type of code I should write to use that parser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)....

Next time - search for an answer before. This is duplicate for sure.

[Little tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack).

Answer (score 4):

You just asked [an almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370092/how-to-use-html-parser-in-c-net-application) and deleted it. Here was the answer I gave before:

---

Try the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

Here's an [example](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples):

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

---

Regarding your extra question regarding regex: do not use Regex to parse HTML. It is not a robust solution. The above library can do a much better job.

Comment: The function `FixLink` is not defined, so this won't compile. It is just an example of what the code might look like - you can't just copy and paste it into your project. Also, you haven't told us what exactly you need to do, so it's very unlikely that this code snippet will be exactly what you need.